# Warning: Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet

Tags: reactjs, axios

i'm getting this warning:

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on a component that hasn't mounted yet. This indicates that you have a side-effect in your render function that asynchronously later calls tries to update the component. Move this work to useEffect instead.

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'review')

setReviews is also not working in my axios function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


function GetRandomReview(props) {
    const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

    axios.get("http://localhost:7000/reviews").then((response) => {
        setReviews(response.data);
    })
    let j = Math.floor((Math.random() * reviews.length));
    console.log(reviews);
    return (
        <div className={props.active ? "carousel-item container-fluid active" : "carousel-item container-fluid"}>
            <h2 className=" testimonial-text">
                {reviews[j].review}
                
            </h2>
            <em>
                {reviews[j].name}
            </em>
        </div>
    )
}

export default GetRandomReview;
```

`

tried to use UseEffect but did't work

Comment: assign axios call to function and call that function in useEffect with no dependency and then again write one more useEffect with reviews as dependency. useEffect (()=>{apiCall},[])  useEffect(()=>{},[reviews])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `useEffect` to call your api, This will first mount your component and then call your api, upon success your state will update which will render data.

Here

```
 <h2 className=" testimonial-text">{reviews?.[j].review}</h2>
      <em>{reviews?.[j].name}</em>
```

This will throw error as your trying refer to a key which doesn't exists yet.
If you want your component render later, but fetch first, then use `useLayoutEffect` hook instead of `useEffect` hook.

```
function GetRandomReview(props) {
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:7000/reviews").then((response) => {
      setReviews(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * reviews.length);
  console.log(reviews);
  return (
    <div
      className={
        props.active
          ? "carousel-item container-fluid active"
          : "carousel-item container-fluid"
      }
    >
      <h2 className="testimonial-text">{reviews?.[j]?.review}</h2>
      <em>{reviews?.[j]?.name}</em>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks its working, can you explain "{reviews?.[j]?.review}" this

Comment: This is called `optional chaining `, [MDN optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)